# Unit Testing - How to Compare Two Paged Collections To Assert All Items Different?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, paging, assert

Had a quick look here, couldn't find a duplicate (correct me if im wrong).

I've got the following Unit Test for some Paging with LINQ:

```
    // Arrange.
    const int locationId = 1;
    const LocationType locationType = LocationType.City;
    int pageSize = 10;

    // Act.
    var postsPageOne = PostService.FindAllPostsForLocationPaged<Review>(locationId, locationType, 1, pageSize);
    var postsPageTwo = PostService.FindAllPostsForLocationPaged<Review>(locationId, locationType, 2, pageSize);

    // Assert.
    Assert.IsTrue(postsPageOne.Count > 0);
    Assert.IsTrue(postsPageTwo.Count > 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(postsPageOne.Count, pageSize);
    Assert.AreEqual(postsPageTwo.Count, pageSize);
    CollectionAssert.AllItemsAreNotNull(postsPageOne.ToArray());
    CollectionAssert.AllItemsAreNotNull(postsPageTwo.ToArray());
```

I want to assert that all items in the collection **postsPageOne** are different to all the items in the collection **postsPageTwo**. (seems like the way to test paging)

Any ideas of how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assert.IsFalse(postsPageOne.Intersect(postsPageTwo).Any());
```

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't sound like the way to test paging to me. I would test paging by having a known dataset, and checking that each page *does* contain the data I'd expect it to. Otherwise your code could just make up random data, and so long as it was different, your test would pass.

Use a small page size (e.g. 2 or 3) to keep the amount of data to test nice and small.

Comment: I agree with your second sentence (checking that each page does contain the data I'd expect it to), i already have that test - this is another test to ensure that each page is unique, is that not a valid test?

Comment: @RPM1984: No, I don't think so - because if you're testing that the pages are { "a", "b", "c"} and { "d", "e", "f" } already, do you *really* need to test that "a" isn't any of "d", "e", "f" etc? Doesn't your test data ensure that?

Comment: I guess your right. Im doing paging with Skip/Take, so really, all im doing is attempting to test the framework. Got your point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an `Id` property on your posts:

```
!postsPageOne.Select(x => x.Id).Intersect(postsPageTwo.Select(x => x.Id)).Any()
```

The way I test paging in my integration tests is to request a large, single-page list, and then break it into pages, requesting each page and keeping track of all IDs in the order they're returned. Then I compare the IDs returned in the large list to the IDs returned by the paging calls and make sure they match exactly.

Comment: It's better to use `Any()` rather than comparing `Count()` to 0 - that way it can stop as soon as it finds anything. Probably not important for a unit test, but worth knowing in general. (Specific to LINQ to Objects, mind you.)

Comment: @Jon: thanks, knew I was forgetting something. I've updated my post.

Comment: In regards to how to do your tests, i expose the paging via another method on my interface (takes in pageSize, pageNumber). So im trying to test that method - using your example of a "single-page list", i would need to use the other method (non-paged), and break that up - therefore i end up not really testing my original method. If that makes sense, probably not. :)

Comment: @RPM: your scenario sounds similar to mine. I just use a large number for pageSize - large enough to accommodate all my test data.